# Windows equivalent for "cat /proc/iomem"

Tags: windows, memory-management

Is there an equivalent program for Windows that "cat /proc/iomem" gives you under Linux?

I'd like an easy way to read the Windows memory map.

Answer (score 2):

How about RAMMAp?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229